# Run background task in foreground application continously in windows IOT core

Tags: uwp, background, uwp-xaml, windows-iot-core-10

I had scenario where background process will start after user login with credentials and background process has to run 24/7 with out stopping, but limitations on background process quota to 10 mins is stopping my background process.is there any other way that background process has to run continuously with out stopping.

Answer (score 1):

Your background task gets cancelled with **ExecutionTimeExceeded** because the maximum time allowed for a background task with ApplicationTrigger to run is 10 minutes if the app is running. If the app is suspended, a background task with ApplicationTrigger is allowed to run for a maximum of 5 minutes. If this time limit is reached, the OS will cancel the task with BackgroundTaskCancellationReason as **IdleTask**.

On Windows IoT Core,you can consider to use background application. Once you deployed the background application, the background application will launch at machine startup and run continuously without any process lifetime management resource use limitations.If the crashes or exits the system will automatically restart them. You can see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/backgroundapplications). And then build an [App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) to provide services to the foreground app and background app.

Comment: I had started background process as out-of-process background task from foreground application. The foreground application giving BackgroundTaskCancellationReason as 'ExecutionTimeExceeded'.will it run continuously without any process lifetime management resource use limitations?

Comment: @phani, I have updated my response. Hope that can help you.